# How to use pd.read_sql with params

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, parameterized-query

I am having trouble with parameterized queries with SQL server when trying to use pd.read_sql.

If I run

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM positions'
pd.read_sql(query,engine)
```

Then I get a good result:

```
        position_id                  position_name
    0             0             ACCOUNTING MANAGER
    1             1                     HR MANAGER
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

But if I run

```
query = 'SELECT ?,? FROM position_names'
params = ['position_id','position_name']
pd.read_sql(query, engine, params=params)
```

Then I get:

```
0   position_id  position_name
1   position_id  position_name
2   position_id  position_name
3   position_id  position_name
...
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot parameterize identifiers like table or column names, only literal values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that instead of reading the column names in as a `param`, you need to read them in as a `columns`.

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

> Parameters:
>
> columns : list, default: None
>
> List of column names to select from SQL table (only used when reading a table).

Comment: What do I put as the columns in the query itself? If I do SELECT *, I still get all the columns even when I do columns = ['position_name']

Comment: If I just do the table name, it works but then is there any way to have queries with more clauses like WHERE

Comment: @Ranvir Mohanlal has a great example of how to use the columns parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to the table name and pass list of columns to extract:

```py
    query = 'position_names'
    columns = ['position_id','position_name']
    pd.read_sql(query, engine, columns=columns)
```